# TortoiseSVN: is there a way to see my colleagues' working copies?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I'm new to TortoiseSVN and can't seem to come up with the magic query to find an existing answer for what I'm looking to do.

I've been doing some refactoring in a codebase new to me and I want to make sure I don't block my colleagues' work because of it; so, I'm trying to find a way to avoid merge conflicts, etc. on their end by making sure I only commit my changes when I'm the only one with major pending changes in an area (i.e. a certain project / solution / folder).

Is there some kind of tooling built-in to TortoiseSVN to help me out that I'm just not aware of? The ideal would be some kind of list view (like the "Working Copy" window) that explicitly called out potential conflicts, but even just a dump of everybody's pending changes would be fantastic enough.

If I'm unclear, I'm basically trying to do the following but with TortoiseSVN instead of TFS:
http://adamprescott.net/2012/09/11/see-what-other-users-have-checked-out-in-tfs/.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With just SVN this is not possible. SVN clients do not have facilities to connect to other clients to see what they are up to. They can only talk to the server.

Perhaps start using branches and committing more often (although this can be a bit painful with SVN). Then you could see your co-workers' commits in the other branches.

Alternatively if you have direct access to their disks via the network you can take a peek, however you'll have to diff things with something else.

Or just teach them to resolve merge conflicts! They'll thank you later.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! That's too bad, but I guess that's a downside on the accepted tradeoffs for our source control setup.